# How to add a series of string inputs that each represent a span of time, in Android?

Tags: java, android, date, time

I am fetching a list of times from server and want to add to show the total time taken. But unable to find how to do. Because the time is in like a normal sentence.

```
15 min 24 s
1 min 56 s
18 min 3 s
2 h 48 min 46 s
```

How to add these data?

Comment: So you are getting a list of Strings like "15 min 24 s", you want to parse them, add them together, parse the result back and display?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes. I'm trying to add them

Comment: actually the data comes in a html file and using jsoup I've extracted this data

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Use `java.time.Duration` class with standard ISO 8601 input strings.

```
Duration total = 
    Duration
    .parse(
        "PT" + 
        "2 h 48 min 46 s"
        .replace( "h" , "H" ) 
        .replace( "min" , "M" )
        .replace( "s" , "S" ) 
        .replace( " " , "" )    
    )
    .plus(
        … another `Duration` object
    )
```

## ISO 8601

Educate the publisher of that data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard that defines many formats for communicating date-time values as text.

The standard [format for a span of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) unattached to the timeline is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning (think of that as "p" for "period") and the `T` separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds.

## Convert your inputs

Your example inputs could be converted to ISO 8601 format.

Replace `min` with `M`. Replace `h` with `H`. And replace `s` with `S`.

Also, delete any SPACE characters. Prepend with `PT`.

```
String input = "2 h 48 min 46 s" ;
String inputIso8601 = 
        "PT" + 
        input
        .replace( "h" , "H" ) 
        .replace( "min" , "M" )
        .replace( "s" , "S" ) 
        .replace( " " , "" )      
;
```

## `Duration`

The modern *java.time* classes in Java include [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html). That class represents a span of time unattached to the timeline on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds.

That class knows how to parse and generate strings in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( inputIso8601 ) ;
```

That class also knows how to do math, adding and subtracting durations.

```
Duration dTotal = d1.plus( d2 ) ;
```

## Example

Let's make a method of that conversion code.

```
public String convertInputToIso8601 ( String input )
{
    String inputIso8601 =
            "PT" +
                    input
                            .replace( "h" , "H" )
                            .replace( "min" , "M" )
                            .replace( "s" , "S" )
                            .replace( " " , "" );
    return inputIso8601;
}
```

Let's use your example inputs.

```
    List < String > inputs = List.of(
            "15 min 24 s" ,
            "1 min 56 s" ,
            "18 min 3 s" ,
            "2 h 48 min 46 s"
    );
```

Test converting the format of those inputs.

```
    List < String > inputsIso8601 = 
        inputs
        .stream()
        .map( this :: convertInputToIso8601 )
        .collect( Collectors.toList() )
    ;
```

Dump to console.

```
    System.out.println(
            inputsIso8601
    );
```

> [PT15M24S, PT1M56S, PT18M3S, PT2H48M46S]

That looks good. Now parse as `Duration` objects.

```
    List < Duration > durations = 
        inputsIso8601
        .stream()
        .map( Duration :: parse )
        .collect( Collectors.toList() )
    ;
```

Dump to console.

```
    System.out.println( durations );
```

> [PT15M24S, PT1M56S, PT18M3S, PT2H48M46S]

That also looks good. Now do the math. The *java.time* classes use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). This means our math operations result in a new fresh object, rather than altering (mutating) the original.

Using conventional syntax to sum the durations.

```
    Duration total = Duration.ZERO;
    for ( Duration duration : durations )
    {
        total = total.plus( duration );
    }
```

Using streams to sum the durations.

```
Duration total = 
    durations
    .stream()
    .reduce(
        Duration.ZERO , 
        Duration::plus
    )
;
```

Dump to console.

```
    System.out.println( "total = " + total );
```

> total = PT3H24M9S

That worked. Your inputs totaled almost three and a half hours.

Here is that code again, all together.

```
    List < String > inputs = List.of(
            "15 min 24 s" ,
            "1 min 56 s" ,
            "18 min 3 s" ,
            "2 h 48 min 46 s"
    );

    List < String > inputsIso8601 = inputs.stream().map( this :: convertInputToIso8601 ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
    System.out.println( inputsIso8601 );

    List < Duration > durations = inputsIso8601.stream().map( Duration :: parse ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
    System.out.println( durations );

    Duration total = durations.stream().reduce( Duration.ZERO , Duration::plus ) ;

    System.out.println( "total = " + total );
```

I imagine we could combine those three streaming statements into a single one. But reading and debugging would likel’y be more difficult.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).